# Как передать параметры из формы в модель для их проверки/валидации?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как передать параментры в модель их для проверси в БД?

Я пытаюсь так, но так не получается:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function actionMy($key_active = '0', $login = '0')
    {

        $model = new Mymodel();
        if($model->validate()){

           return $this->render('yes');
        }

    return $this->render('no');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаете пустую модель Mymodel и никак ее не инициализируете

```
$model = new Mymodel();
```

Ее нужно инициализировать, переданными из формы значениями, здесь же не видно, чтобы вы их как-то передавали внутрь объекта.

```
$model->key_active = $key_active;
$model->login = $login;
```

Comment: Да да да, похоже это то что нужно! Сейчас проверю. Только одно

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Приятного Вам дня.